# How to asynchronously toggle click events on a button

Tags: javascript

I want my  click events to change a buttons text from on to off and back and fourth as many times as they want.

Currently I can click the button then the text content changes to "Reset Filter" then when I click once more the button changes back to Filter per the nested event listener. I want to be able to keep switching between the on and off state.

I have tried while loops and other methods but have learned that this needs to maybe be done async.

```js
const filterBtn = document.getElementById('filter-btn');
// Event Listener to activate filter button
filterBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    filterBtn.textContent = "Reset Filter";
    filterBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        filterBtn.textContent = "Filter";
    })
});
```

```html
<button id="filter-btn">Filter</button>
```

I want to be able to keep switching between the on and off state.

Comment: You only need to add the `eventListener` once, then check what the text is inside of the callback function and change the text accordingly.

Comment: Or toggle a class on it and check for that class

Comment: General rule: adding event listeners inside other event listeners is almost always wrong, especially if you don't call `removeEventListener` to undo the previous one.

Comment: understood so what would be the best course of action if I want to run 2  different functions for each click? I want the first click to activate my filter function, and my second click to cancel and pretty much bring me right back to the start.

Comment: @ChristianMorales Just check the text of the button in the callback function and call whichever secondary function accordingly. `if filterBtn.textContent === "Filter") { filterFunction(); } else { function2(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Just stick to one handler, and flip the text based on the button's current text. You can use the ternary operator for this:

```js
const filterBtn = document.getElementById('filter-btn');
filterBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    filterBtn.textContent = filterBtn.textContent === "Reset Filter"
        ? "Filter" : "Reset Filter";
});
```

```html
<button id="filter-btn">Filter</button>
```